# Margin call and shorting, depends on cash or both cash and held security?

Tags: shorting-securities, margin-call

When you short a stock if the value of the stock goes above a threshold you will get a margin call.  Is this threshold dependent on the total value of your held stock + cash or just available cash?  I'm assuming if the shorted stock goes above your buying power you will get margin call?

Comment: Cash and marginable securities determine the threshold for a margin call.  Above that level, you will get a margin call.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this threshold dependent on the total value of your held stock + cash or just available cash?

It depends on the *equity* in your account, which is based on the market value of all securities and cash.

From ["Short Selling: The Risks and Rewards" (Schwab)](https://www.schwab.com/learn/story/ins-and-outs-short-selling)

> If the value of the collateral in your margin account drops below the minimum equity requirement—usually 30% to 35% of the
> value of the borrowed shares, depending on the firm and the particular
> securities you own—your brokerage may require you to deposit more cash
> or securities to cover the shortfall immediately. [...] If you fail to meet the margin call, your brokerage firm may close out
> open positions to bring your account back to the minimum requirement.

Example

> [Y]ou enter a short position on 100 shares of stock XYZ at $80[.] [A]s long as your 100 shares of stock XYZ remain at $80 per
> share, you'll need $2,400 in your margin account—assuming a 30% equity
> requirement ($8,000 x .30). However, if the stock suddenly rises to
> $100 per share, you'll need $3,000 ($10,000 x .30)—requiring an
> immediate infusion of $600 to your account, which you may or may not
> have.

Comment: It depends on the equity in your account - So basically stock + cash + anything else on the account of value?

Comment: @Lightsout yes but it depends on the type of collateral (cash, Treasuries, bonds, stock, etc.) as they don't all count the same. I'm sure your broker can provide the information you're looking for.

Comment: The Schwab explanation is incorrect.  Short $8,000 of stock on 50% margin so that's $4,000 of equity.  ($4k/$8k = 50%). When the position is worth $10,000, equity has dropped by $2,000 to $2,000 which is 20% margin.  With a 30% maintenance, there is a margin call of $1,000.  Add that to the account and equity becomes $3,000 and the margin level becomes 30% ($3,000/$10,000).

Comment: Be aware that not all securities are marginable - some stocks for example cannot be used for margin - and that there is usually a haircut on the value of the marginable securities that depends on their liquidity and volatility